# Dagger injection not working for "object" in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, dagger

After spending a ludicrous amount of time trying to figure out why my dagger injections weren't working; I realised that the "object" type in Kotlin was the problem.

The following did not work, the injected "property" was null.

```
object SomeSingleton {

    @Inject
    lateinit var property: Property

    init {
        DaggerGraphController.inject(this)
    }
}
```

However, the following DID work just fine:

```
class NotSingleton {

    @Inject
    lateinit var property: Property

    init {
        DaggerGraphController.inject(this)
    }
}
```

I tried google, I tried the documentation but I could not pin point the reason behind this. Also note that I havent tried this with JAVA, JAVA doesnt have the concept of singletons built in anyway.

Why is this the case? Why is a kotlin singleton unable to inject members but a regular non-singleton class can?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Sounds like `object.init` runs sooner than the initialization of your `DaggerGraphController` thing.

Answer (score 17):

If you look into kotlin bytecode you'll find that the code you've written is translated into following:

```
public final class SomeSingleton {
    public static LProperty; property // <- Notice static field here

    public final getProperty()LProperty
    ...

    public final setProperty(LProperty)V
    ...
}
```

As you can see the actual field is static which makes it uneligible for instance injection. You may try to move `@Inject` annotation onto setter method by doing so:

```
object SomeSingleton {
    @set:Inject
    lateinit var property: Property
    ...
}
```

Comment: this still didnt work, the first time around I got an uninitialized field error...after that, a NoClassDefFoundError

i even tried with @field:Inject, same negative result unfortunately

Comment: Doen't work for me. Exception during compilation
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:128)
 at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethod.invoke(InjectionMethod.java:112)
 at dagger.internal.codegen.writing.InjectionMethods$InjectionSiteMethod.invoke(InjectionMethods.java:358)`

Answer (score 12):

A workaround for this can be to extend a BaseClass that consists of the fields to be injected.

```kotlin
object SomeSingleton : BaseClass {
    ...
    ...
}

open class BaseClass{
    @Inject
    lateinit var property: Property

    init{
        YourDaggerComponent.inject(this)
    }

}
```

This does work, although this would leak `this`, which comes up as an android studio warning, to get rid of that make the Base class abstract and instead inject the fields in your original object class

```kotlin
object SomeSingleton : BaseClass {
    ...
    ... 
 // Add the init block here instead of the base class
 init{
        YourDaggerComponent.inject(this)
    }
}

abstract class BaseClass{
    @Inject
    lateinit var property: Property
    
   //Remove the init block from here

}
```

And you Dagger AppComponent interface can be like, any of those function def should work

```kotlin
interface Component{
    fun inject(someSingleton : SomeSingleton)
    //OR
    fun inject(baseClass: BaseClass)
}
```

I hope this helps....

Comment: `.inject` at `YourDaggerComponent.inject(this)` gets an unresolved reference error

Comment: it worked in 2022

Answer (score 7):

I tried to use `dagger.Lazy<YourClass>` and it works

```
 @set:Inject
lateinit var authClient: dagger.Lazy<PlatformAuthClient>
```

Comment: @CaferMertCeyhan, what do you mean by doesn't work? What happens instead?

Comment: I just get this error when trying to inject into a kotlin object: `Dagger does not support injection into Kotlin objects`. This is on Dagger 2.27.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, exception returns: lateinit property [variable] has not been initialized

Answer (score 1):

This was previously allowed by a bug in Dagger. As others described, it is because the properties in a kotlin object are backed by static fields.

See https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/1665 for the fix. It was fixed in 2.27.

Answer (score 0):

You may still need the `@Singleton` decorator on top of your object definition. That decorator doesn't make your class 'singleton', it's just used by Dagger to get all the dependencies in the same spot.